# Apple in-app purchase amount varying From Euro to Dollar

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, in-app-billing

Apple in-app purchase currency conversion from euro to dollar not seems correct. I have declared in euro as  €19.99 but in dollar it shows $16.99.

In App store connect, I created in-app purchase consumable product with price of €19.99 but when I try to buy this product from United States It asking $16.99. Conversion is not seems correct. Someone please explain me how this money conversion will work and how to make same price in both currency?

Comment: What seems incorrect about this? This is how apple prices the tiers.

Comment: @luk2302 I need to make same price amount for both countries

Comment: European prices will include tax. US prices do not

Comment: Not how things work, you do not choose the price, you choose the tier and apple decides the price of that tier in each country. (If I am not mistaken)